Hearts fly up when left click
Hearts fly up when left click
how to make heart shapes like the example, thank you very much.
This is an example web illustration, when clicked the heart has a random color and flies up
https://www.entclassblog.com/2022/02/mtn-.html

I need a piece of code to create a flying heart when I click the mouse
Thank you very much!

Your question unfortunately can't be answered on this site as it lacks detail. You need to specify what programming language you are using, what you've tried so far and where you got stuck. Please see [tour] and [ask]. Then [edit] your question to add the relevant detail.
